# Alternative way to say "sold a project"

Tags: synonyms

My apologies if  this question seems out of place, but I wasn't sure about where else I should ask it (I also couldn't find anything through Google).

I'm in the process of updating my resume, and I'm trying to describe a project that I sold.

Starting the description with "Sold a project worth $xx-xxx" seems somewhat colloquial. Is there a better (more professional) way that I could phrase "sold a project"?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** By "sold a project", I mean from a consulting point of view, i.e. convincing a potential client that their company should use my team's consulting services rather than our competitors'.

Comment: Unfortunately, you give us no context.  We have no idea what kind of job you're looking for or what kind of skills you're trying to describe. A project is (or was) an ongoing enterprise with some goal.  It's an odd thing to "sell".

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I edited my question to provide some clarification/context. To be extra clear, I mean something like this: http://www.4pm.com/selling-projects/

Comment: "sold consulting services"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think that might be more appropriate for independent or freelance consultants who aren't working for consulting firms. In this context, it would be too vague - if you're affiliated with/employed by a consulting firm, I think it's expected that you're "selling consulting services" .

Comment: It may be that "sold a project" is a term of art in your business. If so, then it's fine.

Comment: The answer would depend on your line of business. In software development we often sell projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the phrase "sold a project" to mean that you convinced a potential client to start a project with your firm, provided the context doesn't preclude that interpretation. On the proviso: if, for example, the *project* was a property development and you were a real estate agent, you may need to clarify whether you sold a property or whether you sold the idea of developing the project.

There are at least a couple ways of looking at this.

## 1. Sell = persuade

> **Sell** *verb*
> 2 Persuade someone of the merits of.
> ‘he sold the idea of making a film about Tchaikovsky’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sell)

In this case, what you've done is to persuade the client that it would be a good idea to start a project with your firm. You've 'sold the project', and the next phase might be to negotiate terms and conditions (or the negotiations might have formed part of the persuading). The words "the project" is a metonym for the *idea* of launching said project.

## 2. Project = product

> **Sell** *verb*
> 1 Give or hand over (something) in exchange for money.
> ‘the family business had been sold off’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sell)

In this case, what you're a sales person, and you have convinced the client to sign up to undertake the project itself, not just that it's a good idea. Here, selling a project takes on the same feel as selling a tangible product. What you've actually 'sold' are the services of your firm.

> Wanna know how to better sell your service? Package and position it like a product--these marketing experts show you how. [- entrepreneur.com](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/159488)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, we usually say "bid successfully" or "made a successful bid".

Here, "bid" means to submit the proposal, and "successfully" means that the proposal was accepted.

Answer (score -1):

You contracted with a client for a $xxx,xxx project or engagement. You could go on to summarize the project--e.g., "to improve its marketing strategy" or "to update its payroll system."  You could go on to say that you "successfully competed with other firms to win the contract."
The web site to which you refer is, I believe, using the words "sell" and "buy," which it often places in quotation marks, as metaphors: a project manager needs to persuade a client or a boss to undertake a project.  Unless it's typical in your field, "selling a project" may be inappropriate, more characteristic of real estate than consulting.

Comment: As a reminder, StackExchange answers should *explain*, not merely tell. *Why* would you suggest this formulation? What are some examples of it in real life? What makes it preferable to alternatives?